# When do you need to create abstractions in the form of interfaces?

Tags: oop, interface, abstraction

When do you encourage programming against an interface and not directly to a concrete class?

A guideline that I follow is to create abstractions whenever code requires to cross a logical/physical boundary, most especially when infrastructure-related concerns are involved.

Another checkpoint would be if a dependency will likely change in the future, due to possible additional concerns code (such as caching, transactional awareness, invoking a webservice instead of in-process execution) or if such dependencies have direct references to infrastructure integration points.

If code depends on something that does not require control to cross a logical/physical boundary, I more or less don't create abstractions to interact with those.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Also, use interfaces when

- Multiple objects will need to be acted *upon* in a particular fashion, but are not fundamentally related.  Perhaps many of your business objects access a particular utility object, and when they do they need to give a reference of themselves to that utility object so the utility object can call a particular method.  Have that method in an interface and pass that interface to that utility object.
- Passing around interfaces as parameters can be very helpful in unit testing.  Even if you have just one type of object that sports a particular interface, and hence don't really need a defined interface, you might define/implement an interface solely to "[fake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mock_object)" that object in unit tests.
- related to the first 2 bullets, check out the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) and the [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).  I'm not saying to implement these patterns, but they illustrate types of places where interfaces are really helpful.
- Another twist on this is for implementing a couple of the SOLID Principals, [Open Closed principal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) and the [Interface Segregation principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_segregation_principle).  Like the previous bullet, don't get stressed about strictly implementing these principals everywhere (right away at least), but use these concepts to help move your thinking away from just *what objects go where* to thinking more about *contracts* and *dependency*
- In the end, let's not make it too complicated:  we're in a strongly typed world in .NET.  If you need to call a method or set a property but the object you're passing/using could be fundamentally different, use an interface.

I would add that if your code is not going to be referenced by another library (for a while at least), then the decision of whether to use an interface in a particular situation is one that you *can* responsibly put off.  The "extract interface" refactoring is easy to do these days.  In my current project, I've got an object being passed around that I'm thinking *maybe* I should switch to an interface; I'm not stressing about it.

Comment: "Multiple objects will need to be acted upon in a particular fashion..." Oh yeah, that makes sense. I forgot that you can use interfaces in that scenario too. Usually I find myself making abstract base/super classes for that.

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces abstraction are convenient when doing unit test. It helps for mocking test objects. It very useful in TDD for developing without actually using data from your database.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need any features of the class that aren't found in the Interface...then why not always prefer the Interface implementation?

It will make your code easier to modify in the future and easier to test (mocking).

Answer (score 1):

you have the right idea, already. i would only add a couple of notes to this...

first, abstraction does not mean 'interface'. for example, a "connection string" is an abstraction, even though it's just a string... it's not about the 'type' of the thing in question, it's about the intention of use for that thing.

and secondly, if you are doing test automation of any kind, look for the pain and friction that are exposed by writing the tests. if you find yourself having to set up too many external conditions for a test, it's a sign that you need a better abstraction between the thing your testing and the things it interacts with.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't an interface a way of achieving abstractions? Just like your connection string example, defining an interface reveals the intention of classes that will implement it is all about. That's why the question goes "... in the form of interfaces"

Answer (score 1):

I think you've said it pretty well.  Much of this will be a stylistic thing.  There are open source projects I've looked at where everything has an interface and an implementation, and it's kind of frustrating, but it might make iterative development a little easier, since any objects implementation can break but dummies will still work.  But honestly, I can dummy any class that doesn't overuse the `final` keyword by inheritance.

I would add to your list this: anything which can be thought of as a black box should be abstracted.  This includes some of the things you've mentioned, but it also includes hairy algorithms, which are likely to have multiple useful implementations with different advantages for different situation.

Additionally, interfaces come in handy very often with composite objects.  That's the only way something like java's swing library gets anything done, but it can also be useful for more mundane objects.  (I personally like having an interface like `ValidityChecker` with ways to and-compose or or-compose subordinate `ValidityChecker`s.)

Answer (score 0):

Most of the useful things that come with the Interface passing have been already said. However I would add:

- implementing an interface to an object, or later multiple objects, FORCES all the implementers to follow an IDENTICAL pattern to implement contract with the object. This can be useful in case you have not so OOP-experienced-programmers actually writing the implementation code.
- in some languages you can add attributes on the interface itself, which can be different from the actual object implementation attribute as sense and intent